# ComboBox inside DataGridTemplateColumn not streching to fill the cell

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a DataGrid with a Template Column like below,

```
   <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Doc Name">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridCell}">
          <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
          <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
              <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemTypes}" Width="200" DisplayMemberPath="ItemTyp" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemType}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
           </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I am not sure why am i getting space between top and right. check the image below[image]

How can i get rid of this extra space.

**Edit:** After Removing BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridCell}"[image]

Comment: The space on the right might be due to the combobox having a hardcoded width of 200? No idea what is in that MetroDataGridCell style but try setting margins and paddings to 0.

Comment: @J.H. I have tried margin and padding to 0 no effect. even i have removed the MetroDataGridCell giving the same result.

Comment: @J.H. Removed the width too and gives the same result.

Comment: Maybe you have a style being applied to the combobox? Try adding this to the DataTemplate: <DataTemplate.Resources><Style TargetType="ComboBox"><Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" /></Style></DataTemplate.Resources>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a style being applied to your combobox, you will need to override it to get it to stop being applied.

Try adding this to the DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
  </Style>
</DataTemplate.Resources>
```

Or just this should work too:

```
<DataTemplate.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="ComboBox" />
</DataTemplate.Resources>
```